# Internet Chat laughter in Spanish

Tags: coloquialismos, abreviaturas, jerga-internet

In English we tend to use:

- **lol** = laughing out loud;
- **rofl** = rolling on the floor laughing;
- **lmao** = laughing my a** off;
- **roflmao** = rolling on the floor laughing my a** off.

These are just some of the forms of text laughter that I first encountered on ICQ/IRC back in the 90s / early 00s.   Naturally we also have 'hah', 'haha', and 'bwahahahha' :)

However, when talking to Spanish-speaking friends, aside from the regular 'jaja', I haven't found many other alternatives to express different levels of amusement.  And it feels wrong to laugh sometimes when it's just something that's mildly amusing, for example.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I get a lot of these in text messages: xD.  It means laughing in Spanish SMS. (The surprise is that the x doesn't mean "por.")

Comment: @Brian That emoticon is used everywhere actually; by the way, for those who don't know, it's basically [this face](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_aez9uMrpBoE/TPZiXC0QTeI/AAAAAAAAAIY/Cx37pQG7_n0/s1600/XD.png).

Comment: Oaxaxaxaxaca probably isn't one.

Comment: XD can be extended to a ridiculous amount of D's to measure intensity: XDDDDDD

Answer (score 14):

Lo que yo hago (otros harán otras cosas):

- Te hace gracia y te sonríes `:)`
- Te hace gracia y te ríes `:D`
- Una sonrisa perversa: `jejejeje` (como levantando el labio superior por el lado derecho)
- Una sonrisa malvada: `muahahahaha` (como el malvado que se ríe cuando su trampa ha funcionado)
- Alguien metió la pata, te sorprendes y te hace un poquito de gracia: `Juas`
- *Of course*, también `lol`, `ja`, `jajaja`, y `JAJAJAAJJAJAJAJA`.

Comment: +1 for uppercase "JA".

Comment: +1 Uppercase JA FTW!

Comment: Definitely JAJAJAJA. Even my Norwegian wife knows this one!

Comment: Si las usais, no tengáis miedo de incorporar erratas para que se vea que la risa te impidió escribir bien: mejor JAJAJAJAAAJJA o JAAJAJAJAAJJ que JAJAJAJAJAJA.

Comment: tambien existe el "JAJAAAAAAAAAA" q tiene otro tono

Comment: +1 por la diferencia de intensidad entre juas y jajaja

Answer (score 10):

They use "jajaja": the more "ja", the stronger the laugh. But there are variations, like **jejeje**, which is a less strong laugh and can be a nervous laugh or an "evil" laugh.

Anyway, there seem to be "alternatives" for LOL in Spanish:

- **CMC** (*casi me cago*) = It means "*I almost p****p my pants* (from laughter)";
- **RAC** (*reír a carcajadas*) = lol

I've also seen "**MDR**" (muerto de risa), but it actually originated from the French "*mort de rire*", same meaning; it's used by French speakers along with LOL.

Comment: I've never seen those acronyms you mention, as far as I know, I've only seen XD which is more of an emoticon (laughing face).

Comment: I've never seen those either, but if you got so many positive votes I guess is because some people use them and upvote your answer. I don't think I'll ever use any of those.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen acronyms in Spanish chat, like LOL and ROFL, only onomatopoeias.
I use LOL myself.