# ¿De dónde viene "juas" como risa en internet?

Tags: historia, jerga-internet

Leí con mucha atención la pregunta [Internet Chat laughter in Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/626/1674) y sus interesantes respuestas.

En [una de ellas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/628/1674) se menciona una que uso con frecuencia en internet: **`juas`**.

> Alguien metió la pata, te sorprendes y te hace un poquito de gracia:
>   Juas

Mi pregunta es: ¿alguien conoce el origen de este tipo de risa internetil? En alguna ocasión he oído en la vida real a alguien decir "juas juas" como sonido parecido a "jaja" pero más jocoso. ¿Sería ese su origen?

Comment: Tengo que comprobar esta referencia en alguno de los pocos _Superhumores_ que todavía me quedan, pero creo que Mortadelo y Filemón ya hace tiempo que reían con el "juas". Aunque no creo que sea el origen (quizá ni siquiera influencia), y en todo caso habría que rastrear el uso de la expresión en otros medios escritos, que puede ser casi tarea para una tesis de Licenciatura en Filología.

Comment: @Diego Coincido. Estoy casi seguro de haberlo visto en tebeos "antes de internet"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando quieres expresar risa puedes usar la repetición de infinidad de interjecciones como: *ja,je,ji,jo,ju*.

Una de las muchas combinaciones que puedes usar es *jua*.

> **[ja.](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=ja)**
>
> 1. `interj. U.` para indicar la risa, la burla o la incredulidad. `U. m. repetida.`

*Juas* es la abreviación de varios *jua*. Algo que solemos hacer en español en vez de acrónimos como *LOL* en inglés.

Por eso se puede usar individualmente como en tu ejemplo

> te hace un poquito de gracia: *Juas*

al contrario que *jua* y *je* que para aclarar mejor el sentido se usan repetidamente:

> *jua jua*
>
> *je je je*

Comment: ¿Acaso será que es un énfasis de risa sumamente exagerado? Como lo es lol en Inglés, literalmente nadie se esta riendo en voz alta cuando lo escriben aunque el efecto es de denotar un humor recibido