# ¿De dónde viene el llamar "pis" a la orina?

Tags: etimología

[**Pis**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TBojXv5) figura en el DRAE como

> 1. m. coloq. orina.

sin ninguna indicación de su posible origen o etimología. ¿De dónde viene el llamar coloquialmente "pis" a la orina?

Comment: En algunos diccionarionarios dice del latín _pissare_

Comment: @blonfu por lo que llevo visto, tanto su inserción como la de "pipí" son muy recientes. Yo apostaría por un origen onomatopéyico, dado que "pssssss" se usa como onomatopeya del chorro.

Comment: Puede ser. Lo he puesto como comentario porque no lo veía muy claro. Quería decir _diccionarios_ pero con el movil escribo bastante mal

Comment: Todo parece indicar que viene del latín; por ello, además, las lenguas romances y el inglés (que lo tomó del francés) usan palabras similares. Según [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Latin/pissio), el término es, efectivamente, imitativo.

Comment: Yo también pensaba un origen latino, pero no he encontrado ninguna referencia (como por ejemplo en "orina" o "mear"

Comment: ¿No tendrá que ver con la tendencia de pluralizar las palabras formadas por sílabas repetidas? Véase [_juas_](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/14738/1674) para _jaja_.

Comment: Ni el verbo ni el substantivo son atestados en el latín clásico, pero palabras que provienen de ellos aparecen en tantos idiomas (románicos al inicio, después otros también) en la Edad Media que lo más sensible sería de suponer que existían ya en el latín bajo medieval. Como dice @Carlos, son con certeza de origen onomatopéyico por último, pero es difícil decir exactamente cuándo y dónde surgió la onomatopeya inicialmente. La palabra _pis_ en español parece, por su forma morfofonética, ser un préstamo o del inglés _piss_ o del francés _pisse_; si era indígeno, sería probablemente _piso_.

Comment: En México también se usa "chis."

Comment: También en alemán existe la palabra “Pisort= como “urinario”

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo a [esta referencia](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/pis) la palabra `pis` viene del latin bajo, *pissiare*, que quiere decir "orinar".

> Etimología:
>
> Del bajo latín **pis**siare ("orinar").

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente es un acrónimo de la palabra 'pipi'. Que regularmente se usa para hablarles a los niños para que externen sus necesidades básicas. 'pipi' para orina y 'popo' para defecar

Comment: Creo que "acrónimo" tiene otro significado http://dle.rae.es/?id=0cBv19r

Answer (score 0):

Si en francés orinar se dice pisser, parece claro que podría venir del latín, y que la gente "fina" de cierta época usaba el galicismo eufemísticamente.