# ¿"Ja ja ja" o "jajaja" para reírse en internet?

Tags: jerga-internet, onomatopeyas

Leyendo [Internet Chat laughter in Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/626/1674) se me planteó la duda de si debemos reír diciendo *jajaja*, *¡jajaja!*, *jajajá*, *ja, ja, ja* o *¡ja, ja, ja!* (lo mismo me dejo alguna combinación).

Fundéu en [onomatopeya de la risa](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/onomatopeya-de-la-risa-2040/) menciona que:

> Ha de escribirse sin tildes y con comas (*ja, ja, ja*), como explica la
>   [Ortografía académica](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=UnaffUPrFKKTCxw,).

El enlace nos lleva a este texto:

> Cuando estas expresiones iterativas mantienen su valor estrictamente
>   onomatopéyico y se usan tan solo para reproducir o imitar sonidos, lo
>   normal es separar mediante comas los elementos repetidos: "*De pronto
>   están unidos por una risa floja que no pueden parar, y lloran de risa,
>   y ja, ja, ja, ja, ja...*" (Beccaria *Luna* [Esp. 2001]).

Sin embargo, este "lo normal es separar mediante comas" me hace pensar que no está tan reglado como parece. ¿Es pues lo correcto escribir "*ja, ja, ja*"? ¿Es en algún caso correcto escribir "*jajaja*"? ¿Y por qué se usa casi siempre tres veces la partícula *ja*?

Comment: Gracias @Gorpik - pensé que la coma la había añadido yo por error y la quité : )

Comment: No me extraña; me ha llamado mucho la atención que hubiera una coma al final del enlace. Por suerte, el formato de Stack Exchange separa claramente los enlaces; si lo hubieras puesto directamente en el texto, seguro que el hipervínculo automático habría descartado la coma.

Comment: @Gorpik supongo que fue un error de la RAE al generar la página, pues no tiene mucho sentido. De todos modos, parece que [sí es un carácter válido](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/1983854). Qué cosas se aprenden aquí : )

Comment: Válido, sí; pero poner una coma, o cualquier otro signo ortográfico, al final del URI es buscarse problemas.

Comment: Por que no los dos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El lenguaje evoluciona y me parece que diccionarios y cualquier compendio gramatical deberían ser fotografías de tal fenómeno; no al revés e imponer lo que debe hacerse.

Dicho esto, me parece que no puede aceptarse una ortografía universal para la risa en internet. Si escribiese a mis amigos *ja, ja, ja* ellos pensarían que lo que ellos escribieron pareció absolutamente bobo pero que me río por cortesía.

**Las comas** no me parece que puedan ser obligatorias (las comas representan pausa pero ¿es tan espaciada la risa natural?). Si el *jajaja* representa una onomatopeya, y la risa no es la misma en todas las situaciones ¿por qué representar ésta con una sola variante ortográfica? No es lo mismo una risa discreta que una carcajada; tampoco una pícara que una risa de vergüenza.

**El número tres**: No me parece relevante. Yo lo escribo dos veces, si mi risa no es una carcajada, y más de tres si me parece que he visto algo verdaderamente gracioso.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, a mí también me sonaría rarísimo ver a alguien escribir _ja, ja, ja_, cuando por lo general entre los amigos decimos _jajaja_ o muchos más _jajajaja_ o _juas_, etc. Lo del número viene de que en distintas referencias siempre usan esa cantidad.

Answer (score 4):

No me parece correcto que la forma de transcribir las risas tenga que ser de una determinada forma, del mismo modo que no existe únicamente un tipo de risa. Es imposible establecer una onomatopeya para algo tan variable como la risa, que es algo que sale de dentro y es tan personal de cada uno.

Por ejemplo, estoy de acuerdo con c.p. sobre que si escribo *ja ja ja* en un chat, da la sensación de que lo dicho no me ha hecho en realidad ni pizca de gracia. Si me río de verdad prefiero el *jajaja*. Pero profundizando un poco más, ¿por qué pararnos en el *ja*? ¿Y el resto de variantes?

- La risa de justificación: *Jejeje*.
- La risita tímida: *Jijiji*.
- La risa bobalicona: *Jojojo*.
- La de Papá Noel: *Jou jou jou*.
- La risa maliciosa: *Jujuju*.

¿Y qué tal alargando las sílabas? Quedaría una buena carcajada: *¡Jaaaaaajajajajaja!*

En todo caso, todas estas variantes implican que estás tratando de transcribir una risa particular. Seguramente sea la tuya propia en un chat, o puede que de un personaje en un cómic, o incluso puede que en un texto de una novela. Otra cosa es un texto serio, pongamos un ámbito digamos científico, o periodístico, entonces sí veo bien la opción del *ja, ja, ja* como onomatopeya neutra. También incluso si estás "narrando" la risa:

> Y a partir de entonces fue ya un ja, ja, y ja, ja, y ja, ja...

En [otros idiomas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-linguistic_onomatopoeias) me hacen especial gracia:

- En inglés: *teeheehee*.
- En japonés: *ahahaha* (comenzando por vocal).

Comment: En japonés es ahahah porque ellos escriben de derecha a izquierda jajajajaja

Comment: @DGaleano Ya estoy viendo que las respuestas a esta pregunta pueden ser un ja, ja, y ja, ja...

Comment: Qué de risas podemos echarnos sin tirar de anglicismos... lol :D

Comment: En ruso: `)))))))` es una carcajada.

Answer (score 2):

"ja ja ja" me suena a sarcasmo. Si en un chat alguien escribe algo que no me parece particularmente gracioso, respondería con esa risa. También en el lenguaje hablado esas pausas cortas entre un ja y otro dan ese significado (al menos en mi experiencia). Claro que también la usaría si quiero *simular* que me hizo enojar el comentario. La opinión de que "ja ja ja" es algo sarcástico  también la he visto en esta pregunta de [wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ja-ja-ja-ja-ja-ja-o-jajaja-risa-en-un-texto.1569123/) y también [acá](http://www.elmundo.com/noticia/Se-escribe-jajajaja-/356829).

"jajaja" es más cercana a una risa auténtica(sin el sarcasmo), pero puede verse un poco "rígida" si siempre la escribes así. Sería como una risa muy "controlada". En un chat normal lo común, de acuerdo a lo que he visto, sería una risa tipo: "jajajajajja": algo un poco más relajado y "natural".

Como información adicional, he encontrado varios sitios que mencionan un supuesto estudio acerca de la risa en internet. No he verificado que el estudio en realidad exista, pero al menos es curioso lo que se menciona [allí](http://blogs.elpais.com/antiguru/2013/05/index.html):

> “Las pruebas indican que una verdadera muestra de risa se inicia a partir de los tres “ja” (jajaja) y que a partir de los cinco “ja” (jajajajaja) la persona probablemente sólo se está riendo para adular al otro”

Y dicen sobre el "jaja" (no está en la pregunta pero sería otra variante de risa)

> - La persona no ha entendido el chiste pero le da vergüenza reconocerlo
> - El chiste ha sido muy malo pero no se quiere hacer sentir mal al otro
> - Si es una mujer está claro que quiere terminar una conversación con un pretendiente y le cierra el camino con un “jaja”.
> - En algunas ocasiones significa una risa sarcástica, sobre todo si se pone un espacio entre cada “ja” como por ejemplo “ja ja”